# Python - py.path.new unicode error

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that fetches metadata from FLAC fliles and batch renames them. To do so, I'm using the [py](http://pylib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This program takes the information from FLAC metadata to rename the files
# according to various naming paterns.

"""
rename-flac takes the information from FLAC metadata to batch rename
the files according to various naming paterns.

Usage:
    rename-flac.py (-s | -v) <directory>
    rename-flac.py (-h | --help)
    rename-flac.py --version

Options:
    -h --help      Show the help screen
    -- version     Outputs version information and exits
    -s             Define album as single artist
    -v             Define album as various artist

"""
from docopt import docopt


import subprocess
import sys
import os

from py.path import local


# Dependency check
programlist = ["flac", "python-py", "python-docopt"]
for program in programlist:
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
        ["dpkg", "-l", program], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    dependency, error = pipe.communicate()
    if pipe.returncode:
        print """
        %s is not installed: this program won't run correctly.
        To instal %s, run: aptitude install %s
        """ % (program, program, program)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass


# Defining the function that fetches metadata and formats it
def metadata(filename):
    filename = str(filename).decode("utf-8")

    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
        ["metaflac", "--show-tag=tracknumber", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    tracknumber, error = pipe.communicate()
    tracknumber = tracknumber.decode("utf-8")
    tracknumber = tracknumber.replace("tracknumber=", "")
    tracknumber = tracknumber.replace("TRACKNUMBER=", "")
    tracknumber = tracknumber.rstrip() # Remove whitespaces
    if int(tracknumber) < 10:
        if "0" in tracknumber:
            pass
        else: 
            tracknumber = "0" + tracknumber
    else:
        pass

    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
        ["metaflac", "--show-tag=title", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    title, error = pipe.communicate()
    title = title.decode("utf-8")
    title = title.replace("TITLE=", "")
    title = title.replace("title=", "")
    title = title.rstrip()

    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
        ["metaflac", "--show-tag=artist", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    artist, error = pipe.communicate()
    artist = artist.decode("utf-8")
    artist = artist.replace("ARTIST=", "")
    artist = artist.replace("artist=", "")
    artist = artist.rstrip()

    return tracknumber, title, artist


# Defining function that renames the files
def rename(root):
    if output == str(filename.purebasename).decode("utf-8"):
        print "%s is already named correctly\n" % (title)
    else:
        filename.rename(filename.new(purebasename=output))

# Importing command line arguments
args = docopt(__doc__, version="rename-flac 0.5")
for option, value in args.iteritems():
    global root, choice

    if option == "<directory>":
        root = local(value)

    elif option == "-s" and value == True:
        choice = 1

    elif option == "-v" and value == True:
        choice = 2

    else:
        pass

# 1 - Single artist
# File naming partern: TRACKNUMBER - TITLE.flac
if choice == 1:
    for filename in root.visit(fil="*.flac", rec=True):
        tracknumber, title, artist = metadata(filename)
        output = "%s - %s" % (tracknumber, title)
        rename(root)
    print "Files renamed"
else:
    pass

# 2 - Various artists
# File naming pattern: TRACKNUMBER - ARTIST - TITLE.flac
if choice == 2:
    for filename in root.visit(fil="*.flac", rec=True):
        tracknumber, title, artist = metadata(filename)
        output = "%s - %s - %s" % (tracknumber, artist, title)
        rename(root)
    print "Files renamed"
else:
    pass
```

My code runs fine when `filename` has `utf-8` characters, but when the path to `filename` has `utf-8` characters it get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Main/Programmes/Rename_FLAC/rename-flac.py", line 122, in <module>
    rename(root)
  File "/media/Main/Programmes/Rename_FLAC/rename-flac.py", line 97, in rename
    filename.rename(filename.new(purebasename=output))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py/_path/local.py", line 273, in new
    "%(dirname)s%(sep)s%(basename)s" % kw)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This may seem obvious to more experienced programmers, but I have been trying to resolve that error for a few hours now...

Comment: @r3mus Nope, my terminal is in UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem:

`filename.rename(filename.new(purebasename=output))` crashed because `output` was a unicode mess.

`output` was created by joining `tracknumber`, `artist` and `title`. In metadata(filename) I was reencoding them as unicode with `string = string.decode("utf-8")`, but they were already in unicode, resulting in `output` being mess-up and the crash.

So I deleted `string = string.decode("utf-8")` and it works.

yay.